# tinymce button trigger click not working

Tags: wordpress, tinymce

I'm using wordpress and i add some button on editor 
i wants to trigger click on that well its triggering click 
but not opening light box

for example that button codes looks like

```
<td style="position: relative">
    <a title="Add New Alert" aria-labelledby="content_admin_alert_voice" onClick="return false;" onMouseDown="return false;" class="mceButton mceButtonEnabled mce_admin_alert" href="javascript:;" id="content_admin_alert" role="button" tabindex="-1">
    <img alt="Add New Alert" src="http://www.xyz.com/themes/abc/wp-content/themes/abc/admin/js/../img/icon-alert.png" class="mceIcon"><span id="content_admin_alert_voice" style="display: none;" class="mceVoiceLabel mceIconOnly">
    Add New Alert
    </span>
    </a>
</td>
```

and i'm clicking on #content_admin_alert  but actions not happens like we actually click on that button

Comment: this code snippet is in an editor actually? can you provide an online example or tinymce fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't played with TinyMCE in a while, but the onClick and onMouseDown events are returning false, which would essentially cancel any click actions.

Comment: Yes but when we click on that anchor tag it opens lighbox but when we trigger click with jquery it doesn't do anything